# RxJava 2: How to filter items of infinite stream that emits "List<Item>"?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable` that does never finish. It emits a `List<Item>`. I need to filter out some of those items every time it emits that list. Currently I have this as a solution:

```
mData.getItemsObservable() // Observable<List<Item>>
        .compose(...)
        .flatMapSingle(items -> Observable.fromIterable(items)
                .filter(item -> item.someCondition())
                .toList())
        .subscribe(items -> {
            // ...
        }, error -> {
            // ...
        });
```

Is this the best way to filter out some items? Is there a simpler (more readable) way to do the same?

I've tried this too, but it didn't emit anything:

```
mData.getItemsObservable() // Observable<List<Item>>
        .compose(...)
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) // or like this: flatMapIterable(items -> items)
        .filter(item -> item.someCondition())
        .toList()
        .subscribe(items -> {
            // ...
        }, error -> {
            // ...
        });
```

Comment: Other than using IxJava, the first way is the one. The second one won't complete because you unroll each list item and there is an infinite from them; toList requires finite ones like those inside the flatMapSingle of the first case.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks for explaining. So if I understand correctly, the first method is the way to go to filter out items? It doesn't look as good as the second method. Is there anything that could be improved? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is okay if you want to stick to `RxJava`. Otherwise, you could use [IxJava](https://github.com/akarnokd/ixjava) and perform the filtering directly in a `map` operation:

```
mData.getItemsObservable() // Observable<List<Item>>
    .compose(...)
    .map(v -> Ix.from(v).filter(w -> w.someCondition()).toList())
    .subscribe(items -> {
        // ...
    }, error -> {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with RxJava for now and use the first approach. I'll keep it in mind.